# Why aren't my routes working using UI.Router?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to put together some simple routes and I'm having a really hard time.
Here is a link to the git [repo](https://github.com/gh0st/ncps-mms/commit/758bf6936b64b125c5ca7cb679b3b93b69969487).

When I navigate to `/members` my members load perfectly. When I navigate to `/members/new` the template doesn't load nor does the static template for `/members/test`.

Here is my client side `routes.js`

```
import angular from 'angular';
import 'angular-ui-router';

angular.module('ncps.routes', ['ui.router']).config(($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) => {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/members');

    $stateProvider
    .state('members', {
        url: '/members',
        templateUrl: 'members/members-view.html',
        resolve: {
            membersService: function($http) {
                return $http.get('/members');
            }
        },
        controller: 'MembersController as membersCtrl'
    })
    .state('members.new', {
        url: '/new',
        template: 'I could use a drink right now.'
    })
    .state('members.test', {
        url: '/test',
        template: 'I could use a drink right now.'
    });
});
```

And then in my `index.html` I have my usual `<div ui-view></div>`. So what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Which part is not working?  note your nested states don't have a valid template.

Comment: My `members/new` and `members/test` views never load.

Comment: you mean this view "template: 'I could use a drink right now.'"?

Comment: Yep, I'm trying to go as basic as possible. I figured a static template on a line would be a good place to start. When I try to replicate my `'members'` state that view loads just fine. If I use `templateUrl: 'members/members-add.html'` the template doesn't load.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your configuration is for Nested States & Nested Views. You need to add a

```
<div ui-view></div>
```

in your members-view.html. That is where your nested views go.

Comment: Oh wow. I didn't realize that I was doing nested views when doing `members.add`.